# What can I do with destroyed cargo?

Tags: death-stranding

I just found destroyed cargo, dropped by some other player.

I decided to bring it with me. If nothing else, maybe there's a gameplay mechanism to turn destroyed cargo into materials for crafting tools, but I couldn't find such a feature.

Now I'm wondering if there is a point to picking up destroyed cargo. What can I do with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems my initial assumption was correct: it *is* possible to turn destroyed cargo into crafting materials.

The option to do so only unlocks after you have connected the "*Distribution Center West of Capital Knot City*" to the Q-Pid network during "Episode 2: Amelie".

Doing so unlocks the "Recycle" option, which can turn anything (except delivery cargo that hasn't been destroyed yet) into Metal, Resin, or Chiral Crystals.

Comment: I got the impression that it returns only minuscule amount of materials and generally doesn't worth player's time and effort.

Answer (score -6):

So, to repair destroyed cargo you must pee directly onto it multiple times, after three times it will be fully repaired.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up? It sounds ..counter-intuitive (but still suitable for Kojima).

Comment: That doesn't sound right, but I don't know enough about Death Stranding to dispute it.

Comment: I seen some streemer was splattering repair agent (looke like *pee*ing) onto his damaged cargos and it become repaired. Does @donald suggest to repair it? Is it possible to repair *fully* destroyed cargo?